# Adding Dependencies in Gradle Project which generates .aar file

Tags: android, performance, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a gradle project which generates .aar file which i used to import in another project to run app. Both projects have build.gradle file and i have to add dependencies in both projects gradle file to make application work.

Is there any way we can remove dependency from one build.gradle so that the other project is not affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **aar** file **doesn't contain the nested (or [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.

You should use a **maven repository** (you have to publish the library in a private or public maven repo), you will not have the same issue.
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

An alternative is to add the module as "external module".
Inside a project you can refer **an external module**.

Just use:

```
Project
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
|__app (application module)
   |__build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app' 
include ':myExternalLib'
project(':myExternalLib').projectDir=new   File('pathLibrary')
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':myExternalLib')
}
```

Pay attention to `myExternalLib`.
You have to use the path of the library inside the other project, **not the root** of the project.

Comment: i'm not using maven here.....what i need is to remove a particular dependency from Project generating apk and keep the dependencies only to Gradle project which generates aar file.

Comment: @Ankit I understand but the aar doesn't contain the dependencies that you added in the build.gradle file. It means that you have to add these dependencies also in the projects where you use this library.

Comment: @ Gabriele Mariotti so not possible here?

Comment: @Ankit You can add the library as a module instead of aar file. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I got your point but the original question remains intact, whether this can happen or not.

Comment: @Ankit I don't understand what you mean with "original question remains intact". With an aar file and a flatDir repo the answer is no, you can't. You can avoid duplicating the dependencies only with a maven repo or an external module.