# Cannot access inherited library

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

In my android library I am using [ceddl4j](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ceddl4j&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uJ0ZWIbdNOTI8AfZ5LiQBQ) library but when I build my `library` and try to add it's `aar` file in another `Application`, it is throwing error

```
Error:(75, 44) error: cannot access DigitalData
class file for nl.mirabeau.ceddl4j.DigitalData not found
```

Adding `ceddl4j` into my library with

```
compile group: 'nl.mirabeau', name: 'ceddl4j', version: '1.0.0'
```

I am surely missing something in build configuration of my library, can someone please guide.

Comment: How you are adding the cdddl4j library in your aar and how are you deploying the aar file?

Comment: In build.gradle file of my library i am adding ceddl4j with the given line, then I am building the library and adding the generated aar file into my app as  module @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: The aar file doesn't contain the nested dependencies. Check the documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-gradle/3037/how-to-include-aar-files-in-a-project-in-android/10329/the-aar-file-doesnt-include-the-transitive-dependencies#t=2016110208212615188 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649901/adding-dependencies-in-gradle-project-which-generates-aar-file/34649982

Comment: Thanks man for quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Grabriele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) for providing the information that `aar` file does not contain the nested dependencies, hence the option left is maven repo (public or private).